# Wrapping JavaScriptObjects in case of multiple subclasses?

Tags: gwt

I have a bunch of data entities that all implement `Entity`.  Now I want to expose some of these entities to JavaScript code, but I can't just make a bunch of JavaScriptObject subclasses because of the one-implementation rule.

So, I'm using this kind of thing:

```
public class JsStandardScale3 implements StandardScale3 {

    private JavaScriptObject wrapped;

    public JsStandardScale3(JavaScriptObject wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public native Long getLicenseId() /*-{
        this.@com.activegrade.client.exported.JsStandardScale3::wrapped.getLicenseId();
    }-*/;
```

This works, it's just a lot of work.  The overlay type structure is so much nicer.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you CAN extend JavaScriptObject with multiple subclasses of an interface as long as all of your extensions are from a single "root" extension of JSO.

For example, I have the structure Standard extends Entity and Course extends Entity.  I could NOT do:

```
JsStandard extends JavaScriptObject...
JsCourse extends JavaScriptObject...
```

but I *could* do:

```
JsEntity extends JavaScriptObject...
JsStandard extends JsEntity...
JsCourse extends JsEntity...
```

fantastic!

The only limitation is that every method must be marked final, which works fine for a simple overlay scenario.

Comment: What do your constructors look like in second case?  The docs say that overlay types must have a protected, zero-arg, empty constructor.  But subclasses must call the super's constructor, yes?

Comment: A subclass can call a protected constructor.  You may not have any arguments in any constructors, unfortunately.  I got around this by making static final builder methods that create a new object (with JavaScriptObject.create().cast()) and then set all the appropriate attributes from there